# Why is my Face Fill doing this strange thing

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I already did this once, successfully, unfortunately Blender crashed shortly afterward and my edit wasn't in the autosave file or my saved version so I am stuck with doing it again.  The first time I had all the windows highlighted as shown, and when I filled them, they obliging filled with a nice flat face.  Now it is filling from window to window through the inside of the structure which I do not want.  Why is it doing this?

https://gyazo.com/06ca0382308c77f5a77167e2466a1526

Comment: Are the normals pointing the right way?

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use *Vertex > New Face*.
Shortcut: <kbd>F</kbd>

(while it has a similar name, *Face > Fill* is a different operation)

[image]